Where to find the save file when running with Steam and Proton?
The PC Gaming Wiki for ''My Lovely Daughter'' says that the Windows saves are in

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\GameChanger Studio\My Lovely Daughter

Which fits with what Steam Remote Storage is clearly picking up from my Ubuntu machine:
Folder                 File name
WinAppDataLocalLow     GameChanger Studio/My Lovely Daughter/76561197999437749/save.dat 

But looking for "WinAppDataLocalLow" in .local results in folders for incorrect games, and looking for "GameChanger" doesn't get me anything at all.
Neither does ~/.steam/steam/userdata/<user-id> help, unlike last time.
Nor does <SteamLibrary-folder>/steamapps/compatdata/580170, exist even though that type of path does work for the sequel.
Can someone help me find my save, so I can make copies and backups?

Have you tried "/steamapps/compatdata/580170"? That's based off of My Lovely Wife. I don't game on Linux so I can't confirm or test this in any way.

@qazmlpok - Thanks! I looked there too, works for Wife but not Daughter, strangely.
